# Seam+RichFaces fileUpload should incite reRender

Tags: jsf, richfaces, seam, seam2

I am using RichFaces 3.3 and Seam 2 to develop a web application.

I have a page with the following:

```
<h:form>
<s:div id="myPanel">
  <h:messages/>
  <rich:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{service.uploadEvent}" maxFilesQuantity="1">
    <a:support event="onuploadcomplete" reRender="myPanel"/>
  </rich:fileUpload>
</s:div>
</h:form>
```

In the `service.uploadEvent` method,  I receive the file and add a FacesMessage to let the user know the file uploaded succesfully.

What actually happens is this:

1. The browser requests the page

   - The server starts temporary conversation #1
   - The server renders the page
   - The server sends the completed page and kills conversation #1
2. The client launches an AJAX fileUpload call

   - The server starts temporary conversation #2
   - The server calls `service.fileUpload()`. This method adds a `FacesMessage` to the Conversation-scoped `FacesMessages` seam component.
   - The server returns the response for the AJAX request and kills conversation #2, including all queued `FacesMessage`s.
3. The 'onuploadcomplete' event is received, the client requests a reRender of 'myPanel'

   - The server starts temporary conversation #3
   - The server renders the page, creates a new empty `FacesMessages` for conversation #3
   - The server returns the response for the AJAX request (which contains an empty `<h:messages/>`) and kills conversation #3

I can solve this in a number of ways:

1. By creating a new FacesMessages component which is PAGE-scoped.
2. By marking the conversation as long-running in `service.fileUpload()` and ending it upon doing `fileUploadComplete()`.

The proper way would be to reRender the page in the same conversation as `service.fileUpload()`. Is this possible?

Comment: Hmm, it seems as though RichFaces4 has a solution by specifying the 'render' attribute on fileUpload. This attribute is not available in RichFaces3.

Comment: Just tested using a long-running Conversation. This does not work because Seam pushes out all StatusMessages to the FacesContext before the Render phase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can only be solved by using a custom StatusMessages component and scoping it to a context which will still be available on Rerender (e.g. PAGE or longrunning CONVERSATION).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried replacing `<h:messages />` with `<rich:messages />`? It works well when AJAX actions create new FacesMessages. See http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/rich_messages.html

Comment: Yes I have. It does not render the FacesMessages that are emitted in the uploadListener.